# Pound "" is not geeting display in html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, syntax

i am trying to display a pound sign in my html page.i want to display it through a variable because i am getting the values of sign from an xml file.

Here is Code:

```
<div id="monthly_amt"></div>
<div id="currencySign">\u00A3</div>
```

js code:

```
var sign =$('#currencySign').text();
var monthlypayment = 1000;
$('#monthly_amt').html("\'" + sign +"\'" + monthlypayment);
```

output is

```
'\u00A3'1000
\u00A3
```

js fiddle example is

http://jsfiddle.net/VT2J2/

Comment: I see pound symbol instead of `\u00A3` in your JSFiddle. Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do this, no need of quotes, just concate both variables and it should work:

```
$('#monthly_amt').html( sign + monthlypayment);
```

[**UPDATED FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/ZzeAt/)

Comment: yes this i can do but if i am taking sign value from jsp it is not possible to display. why it is happening any idea ?

Comment: you get it some variable right